# create several blogs in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, blogs

Hi I'm developing a CMS with zend now My problem is how can I have two or more blog in this CMS I can make module with separate layout but which code I must add to my layout two show blogname or else ... maybe is another way?

Answer (score 0):

You may just add another parameter to the action: `module/controller/action/..../whichblog/second/` and create the controller plugin switching the layout and the logic.

You may be interested in creating blog service instead blog module.